# command that will take a file and separate each word so its on its own line

Tags: linux, command-line, text-formatting

I have a file which has around 17523 words in it and I need to 
separate each word so it is on its own line (a word is defined to be a contiguous sequence of letters, so 1 letter words don't count) and to remove all blank lines. i don't know why this isn't working:

```
cat file.txt | tr [[:upper:]] [[:lower:]] | tr -d '\n' | tr " " '\n'
```

Comment: Next time please be explicit instead of saying "_i don't know why this isn't working_". You haven't said what happened. (You have said what you're trying to achieve though - thank you.) You haven't provided an example file that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Grep's `-o` option is perfect for this: it prints each match on its own line.

```
grep -E -o '[[:alpha:]]{2,}' file.txt
```

And if you want that lowercased

```
grep -E -o '[[:alpha:]]{2,}' file.txt | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
```

Note that the grep regex uses double brackets and tr does not: that's because a character class in a regular expression needs to be contained in brackets, while tr does not use regular expressions, it uses sets of characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
cat file.txt | tr [[:upper:]] [[:lower:]] | tr '\n' ' ' | sed -E 's/[ \t]+/\n/g'
```

Your `tr -d '\n'` is joining all the words by removing spacing. The `tr '\n' ' '` above preserve spacing.

Then, the spacing needs to be converted to one space, sed above does that.
Converts several spaces (or tabs) `[ \t]+` to one newline `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question on the title:

> command that will take a file and separate each word so its on its own line

You could do:

```
<file tr '\n\t\r' ' '' '' ' | tr -s ' ' '\n'   # needs three spaces !
```

It will convert newlines, tabs and carriage returns to spaces and then …
convert any run (`-s`) of spaces back to **one** newline.

You could take advantage of the tr command and use it to also convert uppercase to lowercase in the same call:

```
<file tr '[:upper:]\n\t\r' '[:lower:]   ' | tr -s ' ' '\n'
```

Or you can do exactly the same in GNU sed (mind that this will slurp the whole file into memory and assumes that no NUL bytes exist inside the file):

```
<file sed -zE -e 'y/A-Z\n\t\r/a-z   /;s/ +/\n/g'
```

Then, to answer the question in the body:

> (a word is defined to be a contiguous sequence of letters, so 1 letter words don't count) and to remove all blank lines.

you can remove words with characters other than a-z, one character words, and empty lines:

```
sed -E '/[^a-z]/d;/^.$/d;/^$/d'
```

It could be reduced to the slightly more cryptic:

```
sed -E '/[^a-z]/d;/^(.|)$/d'
```

All in one line, either:

```
<file tr '[:upper:]\n\t\r' '[:lower:]   ' | tr -s ' ' '\n' | sed -E '/[^a-z]/d;/^(.|)$/d'
```

Or:

```
<file sed -zE -e 'y/A-Z\n\t\r/a-z   /;s/ +/\n/g' | sed -E '/[^a-z]/d;/^(.|)$/d'
```

Commented version (works in GNU sed):

```
# Source `file` and use sed with the `zero` option (-z) and Extended Regex (ERE `-E`)
<file sed -zE -e '
    # Transliterate (-y) UPPER to lower and convert control to space.
y/A-Z\n\t\r/a-z   /
    # Restore consecutive spaces to **one** newline.
s/ +/\n/g
    # Second call to sed.
' | sed -E '
    # Delete (d) lines that have nay character not in the range a-z.
/[^a-z]/d
    # delete any line with one character or empty.
/^(.|)$/d
'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat file.txt | awk 'NF''{gsub(/ /,"\n"); print tolower($0)}'
```

NF removes lines containing only blanks or tabs, then `gsub` will change spaces between words `/ /` by new lines`"\n"`. finally, `tolower($0)` will capital letters.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo '  HTE ONTE NOTEH ONTEH E E O  AOE  ' | perl -pe '$_ =~ s/\b\w\b//g; $_ =~ s/\W*(\w+)\W*/\L$1\n/g'
hte
onte
noteh
onteh
aoe
```

This uses Perl to first remove any single-character words from the input, and then to extract and lower-case each remaining word with non-word characters removed and with each word on its own line.

Answer (score 0):

`perl -nale 'foreach $word (@F) {print $word;}' file.txt`

or even more briefly:

`perl -nale 'for (@F) {print}' file.txt`

The `perl` command line options are:

`-n` - process each input line, **n**o printing
`-a` - **a**uto split each input line into words and store the result in special variable `@F` (list of fields)
`-l` - remove **l**ine breaks (`\n`) from the end of each input line and restore line breaks at the end of each output line
`-e` - **e**xecute code given on the command line

The code then iterates over each word in `@F` and prints it.

Another option is to just print the words in `@F` separated by newlines:

`perl -nale 'print join("\n", @F)' file.txt`