# Print one word more than one charter on new line using awk, sed, grep

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I have a text file, I want to print every word (more than one character) on new line. If a word consist of a single character, it must be handled as part of the following word and printed with it on a new line. If it is in the middle between two words it must follow the second word. example:

```
Unix & Linux Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for users of Linux,
```

output

```
Unix
& Linux
Stack
Exchange
is 
a question 
and 
answer 
site
for
users
of
Linux
```

Comment: What do you mean by "if it is in the middle between two words it must follow the second word"? What should happen to a one character word if there's no word following it?

Comment: This is strongly related to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/472204/4667 -- is this the same homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd reach for Perl-flavoured regex here:

```
$ echo "$s" | grep -Po '((^|\s)\K\S\s+)?\S{2,}'
Unix
& Linux
Stack
Exchange
is
a question
and
answer
site
for
users
of
Linux,
```

You can do the same with extended regex, but as it doesn't have pcre's lookarounds, you end up capturing the leading space:

```
$ echo "$s" | grep -Eo '((^|[[:blank:]])[^[:blank:]][[:blank:]]+)?[^[:blank:]]{2,}'
Unix
 & Linux
Stack
Exchange
is
 a question
and
answer
site
for
users
of
Linux,
```

I would have liked to use a word boundary marker prior to the 1-character word, but `&` is not a word character, so the word boundary is not useful.

Comment: I really appreciate the answer. Very helpful! I Googled so much but I was not aware that there was similar question out there. thanks for sharing!   Can I use the same regex in an `awk` statement?

Comment: The extended regex yes. The Perl regex no.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
sed -r 's/([^ ]{2,}) /\1\n/g' file
Unix
& Linux
Stack
Exchange
is
a question
and
answer
site
for
users
of
Linux,
```

Check if a space is preceded by 2 or more non-space char pattern, and substitute by "back reference" pattern plus `<LF>` char.

Comment: Very elegant solution